# Easy PHP Development Server 16.1 PHP MyAdmin

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I recently downloaded Easy PHP 16.1 and tried to open my phpmyadmin and it shows blank page.

My Environment is Windows 8 32 bit system, freshly installed os.

I have also installed Eclipse for android development in the same system and not sure will there be any port conflicts.

The apache server is running fine and i could execute the php files with echo statement.

Note : I tried with xampp also, and i got a blank screen for xampp too.

Comment: What's in the error logs?

Comment: let set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: This is for php code right? My phpmyadmin is not opening up. Where should i write error_reporting(E_ALL)?